# asp.net custom validator doesn't has attribute controltovalidate on postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I use my jQuery plugin with asp.net custom validator in a page:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtModel" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="modelValidator" Display="Static" ControlToValidate="txtModel" ClientValidationFunction="validateDetails" EnableClientScript="true" runat="server" Text="My Message" />

<script type="text/javascript">

function validateDetails(sender, args) {
    var controltovalidate = $(sender).attr('controltovalidate');
    args.IsValid = $('#' + controltovalidate).data('MyPlugin').hasValidValue();
}

    $(function() {
        $('#<%=txtModel.ClientID %>').MyPlugin({
            validator: $('#<%=modelValidator.ClientID %>') //In order to execute validation check when values inserted
        });
    });
 </script>
```

As you can see, is addition to validator execution at postback, I want to execute the validator inside the plugin and therefore I passed the validator in the plugin options.
Whenever the plugin executes the validator (using `ValidatorValidate(options.validator.get(0));` the validateDetails function works perfectly.
The problem is in post back. When I press on a button that makes a postback the validateDetails function fails on `var controltovalidate = $(sender).attr('controltovalidate');` because the sender suddenly doesn't have `controltovalidate` attribute. Why is that? How can I make the function works on post back?

Comment: @mshsayem: No. I am using this validateDetails function only for modelValidator validator.

Comment: If it is for only one validator, why are you getting the control like that? Just `$("#txtModel")` should work, right? like `args.IsValid = $('#txtModel').data('MyPlugin').hasValidValue();` ?

Comment: @mshsayem: You right, but I prefer the validateDetails function to not be dependent on elements ids. Moreover, the validateDetails function stays on different js file and therefore I don't have the client id of the rendered txtModel element.

Answer (score 0):

@Naor: Try calling your jquery function on button click event,and validate values.

Comment: I believe you didn't understand the question.