# Validate dropdown from custom control in page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I  have a custom control included in a form that includes a dropdown list. The form has a number of other required fields, so i was wondering how to validate this dropdown.

```
<gaia:TextBox ID="TitleTextBox" runat="server"/>
<gaia:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="TitleTextBox"
                    ErrorMessage="Please fill in the press release title" Text="*" Display="None" ValidationGroup="save" />

<CN:ProductCategoryDropDown runat="server" ID="ProductCategoryDropDown" />
<gaia:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="ProductCategoryValidator" OnServerValidate="ProductCategory_Validate" ValidationGroup="save" 
                    Display="None" Text="*" ErrorMessage="Please select a category"  />
```

the code behind looks like this

```
protected void ProductCategory_Validate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = (ProductCategoryDropDown.SelectedValue>0);
}
```

On the customvalidator above, I purposely left out the 'ControlToValidate' because it throws an error.

Please help.

Comment: I forgot to check whether page was valid. SOLVEDPut 

    if (!Page.IsValid)
    {
         return;
    }

on the submit code..

Comment: Try out this other article: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987615/asp-net-custom-validator-doesnt-has-attribute-controltovalidate-on-postback][1]

Hope this can helps you!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987615/asp-net-custom-validator-doesnt-has-attribute-controltovalidate-on-postback

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to include the `CustomValidator` in the `UserControl`.

Then you could provide a property for the Validation-Group and another `ValidatorEnabled` to set the validator group and enable/disable the validator.